# updating mysql through form data retains old values

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am battling with the below code. The below is intended to:

1) Read data course data from database 
 2) Display data in a form ready for editing 
 3) Once edited, on submit, pass edited values to database

The issue I am getting is that I am able to execute 1 and 2 with no issues, but when I pass the edit data to database in step 3, the old values which where presented in step one are instead passed. How to I get the edited values to be passed and not the old values?

Thank you in advance

```PHP
$readQuery="SELECT * FROM course WHERE course_id={$id}"; 
$readResult=mysqli_query($connection, $readQuery);
validateQuery($readResult);         

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($readResult))
{
$courseId=$row["course_id"];
$courseName=$row["course_name"];
$courseDescr=$row["course_descr"];
$courseCost=$row["course_cost"];
$courseDuration=$row["course_duration"];
}
?>
<form action="course_man.php?page=<?php echo $page?>" &id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <!--Course ID <input type="text" name="course_id" value="<?php //echo $courseId;?>"/><br/>-->
                Course Name <input type="text" name="course_name" value="<?php echo $courseName;?>"/><br/>
                Course Description <textarea name ="course_descr" rows="6" cols ="30" ><?php echo $courseDescr;?></textarea><br/>
                Course Cost <input type="text" name="course_cost" value="<?php echo $courseCost;?>"/><br/>
                Course Duration <input type="text" name="course_duration" value="<?php echo $courseDuration;?>"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <?php   

    }
    if(isset ($_POST['update']))
    {

    $updateQuery="UPDATE course SET ";
    $updateQuery.="course_name='{$courseName}', ";
    $updateQuery.="course_descr='{$courseDescr}', ";
    $updateQuery.="course_cost={$courseCost}, ";
    $updateQuery.="course_duration={$courseDuration}, ";
    $updateQuery.="WHERE course_id={$id}";
    $check = mysqli_query($connection, $updateQuery);
    mysqli_error($connection);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through your code line-by-line. How is the script supposed to get the new values from the form? A sql query is executed in all cases and the variables such as $courseName are set with the old values anyway. Now, when we get to the updating part, variables are still set with old values.

```
if(isset ($_POST['update']))
{

$updateQuery="UPDATE course SET ";
$updateQuery.="course_name='". $_POST['course_name'] ."', ";
$updateQuery.="course_descr='". $_POST['course_descr'] ."', ";
$updateQuery.="course_cost=". $_POST['course_cost'] .", ";
$updateQuery.="course_duration=". $_POST['course_duration'] .", ";
$updateQuery.="WHERE course_id=". $_POST['course_id'];
$check = mysqli_query($connection, $updateQuery);
mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

Move this code up before SELECT... query. And do not forget to sanitize user data before putting it into the query! Use mysqli_real_escape_string() http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php or something else.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit form to course_man.php it again fetch data from db and your below variables will be overwritten with db values.

```
$courseId=$row["course_id"];
$courseName=$row["course_name"];
$courseDescr=$row["course_descr"];
$courseCost=$row["course_cost"];
$courseDuration=$row["course_duration"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

`$updateQuery="UPDATE course SET course_name = '$courseName', 
     course_descr    = '$courseDescr',
     course_cost     = '$courseCost',
     course_duration = '$courseDuration'
     WHERE course_id =  $id
     ";`